# Why is variable value from one if not being rendered when when called in another in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP, and combining that language with HTML is more confusing. I am sure there is a simple solution to it but with all the answers out there I still unable to make it work for me.

Here is the piece of code. I have an if statement that checks for `x_filter`, if its true it saves its value in `$var`.

My problem: I need to rend the value of that `$var`, once the next if statement, which looks for `x_detail`, is `true`. The code as is will not render anything, and also not give any errors and I can't understand why? Any input is much appreciated.

```html
<?php if ($strName == 'x_filter'): ?>
  <?php $var = $this->{$strName}; ?>
  <?php echo $var; ?>
  <!--The echo statement produces the correct value here -->
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($strName == "x_detail"):  ?>
  <span class="filter_value">Value of variable should be here: <?= $var; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It will  be undefined if the first condition is not met.

Comment: You also don't need to jump in and out of PHP like that. The first 6 lines could be within a single `<?php`

Comment: _“and also not give any errors”_ - go and enable proper PHP error reporting first of all then!

Comment: Your problem is not specific to PHP, it will happen in any language: the variable `$strName` cannot be at the same time `'x_filter'` and `"x_detail"`. If the first, the value is defined and not displayed, if the second, it's displayed but not defined.

Comment: The alternative `if`/`elseif` syntax is valid, and preferable to some, I don't find that much of an issue - what I don't understand, and loathe, is the constant in/out of PHP for every line like that. @Kaddath

Comment: @Qirel yep, my comment was mostly about the in/out formatting, the part about the `endif` (not `elseif` which is actually very useful) was just an addition. They seem to completely avoid the `{}` syntax in Worpress and use `endif/endwhile` everywhere

Answer (score 0):

it's just because when your first condition doesn't met your variable $var remains undefined.